# react filter state by id if not set default value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a state that looks like:

```
Object {active: false, class: "myclass", id: 1}
```

and I want to get value here like:

```
{this.state.filter(cls => cls.id==1) ? 'anyclass'}
```

Here I want if there is `id` value to 1 then it should return me `myclass` if not then I want some dafault value like `anyclass`

How can I do filter like this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

how about `{this.state.id === 1 ? this.state.class : 'anyclass'}`?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use map data structure available with immutable.js:

```
import {List, Map} from 'immutable'; // refer the require 

var map = Map(data.reduce(function(previous, current) 
{ 
    previous[ current._id ] = current;
    return previous;
}, {}));

//then, you can directly fetch with id, and check your logic:
var id='param'
state.filter.get(id) === 1 ? state.class : 'anyclass'
```